How to encode MP4 file with Webcodec's VideoEncode API
I'm trying to make a tool that uses Webcodec's VideoEncoder API to compress/convert a submitted video file locally.
The problem is that the outputted video after the encoding comes out with a fraction of a second and full of noise (no image).
I've used Vanilagy's MP4 Muxer for Multiplexing. Here's my code:
async function main() {
    const videoFile = files[0];
    const arrayBuffer = await readFileAsArrayBuffer(videoFile);

    let muxer = new Muxer({
      target: new ArrayBufferTarget(),
      video: {
        codec: "avc",
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
      },
      fastStart: "in-memory",
      firstTimestampBehavior: "offset",
    });

    const frame = new VideoFrame(arrayBuffer, {
      format: "I420",
      codedWidth: 1280,
      codedHeight: 720,
      timestamp: 0,
      duration: 0,
    });

    let encoder = new VideoEncoder({
      output: (chunk, meta) => muxer.addVideoChunk(chunk, meta),
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
    });

    encoder.configure({
      codec: "avc1.64001f",
      width: 1280,
      height: 720,
      bitrate: 2_000_000, // 2 Mbps
      framerate: 25,
    });

    encoder.encode(frame, { keyFrame: true });

    frame.close();

    await encoder.flush();
    muxer.finalize();

    let { buffer } = muxer.target;

    downloadBlob(new Blob([buffer]));
  }

Link to REPL so you can test it
I've tried different video codecs and even importing the video from a HTML Video element, but then I only got some frames of the video, not the full length.
I've already seen this thread but can't find a solution either.

I haven't tested your code but from looking: (1) "Output video comes out with a fraction of a second" Are you updating timestamp: 0 and duration: 0 of each frame? If not, try to make that { } object as a separate variable that you can update (with a new frame timestamp and frame duration,) usually in millisecs, before using it in the function call const frame = etc. (2) "Full of noise (no image)"  sounds like the first frame is not being written as a keyframe or an expected keyframe in your video timeline is not encoded (either is no bytes, or bytes are marked as P-frame).

As mentioned in this example Video Processing with WebCodecs, valid input sources of a Video Frame are:

Canvas
ImageBitmap
MediaStreamTrack

What you can do to achieve the desired result is to paint each individual frame of the input video to a canvas which you can then be referenced as the first argument of the VideoFrame object.

You have a conceptual problem: You can not create videoFrames correctly out of an ArrayBuffer generated from the video file. To generate the videoframes you have two options:
First and simplest: As suggested above, you can turn your videoFile into a videoStream and then paint it to a canvas, or even better, use the mediaStreamTrackProcessor API.
Altough this is the simplest, there is a big drawback: You won't get consistent frame rate... This happens because when you choose to use the browsers API's, you levae the decoder control for them and they have algorithims that, eventually skip frames.
Second and hardest, but will give you total control: Use mp4Box to extract the encodedVideoChunks relative to each frame and then decode them. By doing so, you'll have access to every frame of the video file as well as the metadata. In this URL you can find a fully functional example: https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/samples/video-decode-display/
